# How to find gcds of all contigious subarray in less than O(N^2) complexity

Tags: python, greatest-common-divisor

I need to find all possible gcd of all **contiguous** subarray of a very large array. I need a solution less than O(N<sup>2</sup>) time.

Here is my solution with O(N^2).

```
from math import gcd
lst = [5,3,5,8,9,4,5,6] # A very long list
gcds = {1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0}#  .....  All initialized with 0
for i in range(N):
    g = lst[i]
    for j in range(i+1,N):
        g = gcd(g,lst[j])
        if g== 1:
            gcds[1] += N-j
            break
        gcds[j] += 1
```

Comment: Sure...  Input : 3 6 9 4  Output : 3: 3      1:3   Because gcd(3,6) = 3. gcd(3,6,9) = 3. gcd(3,6,9,4) = 1. Agian gcd(6,9) = 3 gcd(6,9,4) = 1. gcd(9,4) = 1.  So, there is 3 gcd with value 3 and 3 gcd with value 1.... So, I nee output 1:3, 3:3

Answer (score 1):

The key to solving this is that the GCD function is associative. That is `gcd(a, gcd(b, c)) == gcd(gcd(a, b), c)`

There are exactly `n(n+1)/2` contiguous subarrays and each has one GCD these can be calculated like by simply taking the GCD of adjacent elements and then repeating this for the results of each row in the triangle:

```
5 3 5 8 9 4 5 6
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1 1
    1 1 1 1
     1 1 1
      1 1
       1
```

```
from fractions import gcd
output = []
lst = [5,3,5,8,9,4,5,6]
while lst:
    o = []
    x = lst[0]
    for l in lst[1:]:
        o.append(gcd(l, x))
        x = l
    output.extend(o)
    lst = o
print output
```

Results in `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` which is `28` ones.

The complexity of this is `n(n+1)/2` or O(n^2). Let us ignore that `n=len(input)-1`.

This also works for the other example

```
3 6 9 4
 3 3 1
  3 1
   1
```

The result of the program is `[3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1]`

Using `Counter`, this can output a histogram rather than a list:

```
from fractions import gcd
from collections import Counter
output = []
gcds = Counter()
lst = [3, 6, 9, 4]
while lst:
    o = []
    x = lst[0]
    for l in lst[1:]:
        v = gcd(l, x)
        gcds[v] += 1
        o.append(v)
        x = l
    lst = o
print gcds
```

prints `Counter({1: 3, 3: 3})`

Comment: The solution is O(N^2).  I need better than that.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.